# AR Foundation: How to stop model from moving when tapping buttons on the screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I am using the regular "Place On Plane" Script for AR Foundation and tried a few custom ones but everytime I am pressing a button on my screen, the 3d model moves to the corresponding position on the plane where I tapped the screen.
How can I stop this and only make the object moveable when I select it and then drag it around? Or is there even another way to do changes on my UI so buttons won't let me tap on the plane?

Answer (score 0):

In your plane manager find the script that places objects on the plane (in Unity's sample codes it's `PlaceOnPlane.cs`), you can define that only the first tap would be the one that put the object in position.